# Why does the second grep command not work?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a folder named "components" and within that folder a file name "apple"

If I cd to "components" folder and execute the following command:

```
ls | grep -G a*e
```

It works and returns apple correctly.

However, if I do not cd to components folder and execute the following command:

```
ls components | grep -G a*e
```

It does not work and returns blank. What could be the reason?

A third grep command below works fine.

```
ls components | grep ap
```

The actual filename I am grepping is complex. So I need the `grep -G` tag to work.

Comment: Does `ls components | grep -G "a*e"` give you the desired results?

Comment: No, it does not give the results. It returns blank.

Comment: What's the output of `grep -V` and `bash --version`? What operating system and kernel are you using?

Comment: Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes as you're trying to parse the output of `ls` and by not using quotes around your regexp, it's actually not a regexp but a globbing pattern instead, applied before grep even sees the resulting string.

Comment: Why did you add the `-G` option to your grep command? I've never seen it used and it actually doesn't do anything at all in this context since that's the default behavior so I'm wondering if you intended to do something different and just added the wrong option, in which case we could help you with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unquoted, `a*e` is a shell glob pattern that is expanded by the shell **before** grep runs.

When you are in the directory, this:

```
ls | grep -G a*e
```

becomes

```
ls | grep -G apple
```

As you have a file named 'apple' this matches.

When you are not in the folder, and you run:

```
ls components | grep -G a*e
```

the shell again attempts to expand the glob pattern.

If there is any file in your current directory that matches (for example, "abalone"), then the glob will expand to that. It may expand to multiple strings if there is more than one such filename (for example, "abalone", "algae"). The command becomes something like:

```
ls components | grep -G abalone
```

```
ls components | grep -G abalone algae
```

In the first case, you will get blank output unless `components` directory also contains that filename.

In the second case, grep will ignore the directory entirely and attempt to find the string "abalone" inside the file "algae".

There is a third possibility: the glob fails to find anything. In this case, grep **will** receive the regexp `a*e`. The `-G` option to grep tell it to use BRE-style regexp. With these, `a*e` means "zero or more `a` followed by `e`". This is equivalent to saying "contains `e`".

In that case, you should see `apple` in your results regardless of whether you are in `components` or not. In a comment, you say that `ls components | grep "a*e"` returned nothing. As quoting should force precisely the same result as this third case, this is surprising.

---

Note that if you are intending to use globs you don't need grep at all:

```
cd components
ls a*e
```

```
ls components/a*e
```

Comment: The current directory does not have any file named apple. So grep did not expand the wild card. But as you explained, `ls components/a*e` did the work for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

`a*e` is a glob, not a regex. It's important to understand the difference.

The shell expands globs in unquoted arguments by matching the argument with available files. The `*` in `a*e` means "any sequence of characters not containing a directory separator", so it will match the filename `apple` (or `accolade.node`) as long as that file is present in the current directory. Glob matches are complete, not substring matches.

So when you execute `grep a*e` in a directory which contains the file `apple`, the shell will replace `a*e` with the word `apple` before invoking grep, making the command `grep apple`. If the directory also contained the file `accolade.node`, the shell would have put that into the command line as well; `grep accolade.node apple`. That's very rarely what you want to happen to grep arguments (other than filename arguments), so it's highly recommended to get into the habit of quoting arguments.

Unlike the shell, grep is based on regular expression matching. In a regular expression, `*` means "any number of repetitions of the previous element", so the regular expression `a*e` will match `e`, `ae`, `aae`, `aaae`, and so on. Since grep does substring matching (by default), those strings could be anywhere in the line being matched. That will match the `e` in `apple`, for example, but it will also match any other line which contains an `e`, such as `electronics`. (That makes it a bit surprising that `ls components | grep "a*e"` did not match `components/apple`. Perhaps there was some typing problem.)

In order to match `a` followed by a sequence of arbitrary characters followed by an `e`, you could use the regular expression `a.*e` (i.e. `grep "a.*e"` -- note the use of quotes to avoid having the shell try to expand that argument as a glob). But that will probably match too much, if you're expecting it to do the same thing as the glob `a*e`. You might want to add some restrictions. For example, `grep -w`  forces the match to be complete words. And (with gnu grep, at least) you can use `grep -w "a\S*e"` to match a complete word which starts with `a` and ends with `e`, using the `\S` shortcut (any character other than whitespace).

You very rarely want to use `-G`, by the way, particularly since it's the default (unfortunately). Most of the time, you'll want to use `grep -E` in order to not have to insert backslashes throughout your pattern. Please read `man 7 regex` for a quick overview of regex syntax and the difference between basic and extended Posix regexes. `man grep` is also useful, of course.

Comment: That's a good point about `ls components | grep -G "a*e"` not matching anything. Something doesn't add up.

Comment: I would add that parsing `ls`is [generally a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (it's intended for *displaying files to the user*, not getting lists for further processing). To find files based on a complex pattern, it's generally better to use [extended globs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) (which is similar in power to regular expressions, but has very different syntax).

Comment: @Gordon or `find`, but that's drifting pretty far afield from the original question.